# For algorithm-design-related debugging-type questions, is compact pseudocode better than a runnable, but very long, MCVE?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, minimal-reproducible-example

Suppose one has a question about a problem with a *specific piece of code*. The code produces incorrect output in a small number of cases, and works as intended the rest of the time. The asker believes that the bug is *entirely related to program logic/algorithm design choices*, and is not related to any syntax or language features.

It is possible to provide a runnable MCVE using a Stack Snippet, but even in the most minimal case, it takes up a lot of space. Much of this is due to things like constructing a nested table for the user interface, and defining a bunch of helper functions to be used within the three main functions which are the focus of the question.

Due to the question's extreme length (it took a few revisions just to get it to fit within the character limit!), it has very low views after 2 days despite having one of the largest and most active tags, and the asker is dubious whether it will ever get answered. If adding a bounty doesn't work, and there are still no answers by the end of the week, is it a good idea for the asker to:

- **Edit the question to completely replace the MCVE with a pseudocode "summary" of the algorithm instead?** (This would make the question much more compact, but no longer runnable. It would also allow removing the part of the text which explains what to do with the interactive portion.)

Comment: "problem with a specific piece of code" -- question is, whether such problem is suitable for SO in the first place.

Comment: The only approach that's likely to garner an answer would be to massively simplify the problem. I.e cut it down by a factor of 100 or so.

Comment: 2 days, or even a week... way too short a time to make you do anything but wait. There's no SLA here, and especially for something obscure/complex, it may take much longer, if ever. If you need a answer you your specific problem fast, then SO is probably not the ideal place to solicit it.

Comment: @RobertLongson I don't know about "factor of 100", but switching to pseudocode *would* "massively simplify the problem."

Comment: @DanMašek It's not a time-sensitive issue, but it seems pointless to leave a question that people are very likely not to read, especially if that means it has little use to future visitors to the site. The pseudocode version could remove the kind of stuff that might make the specific piece of code "too localized," and so make the problem more general too.

Comment: you have to remember you're competing with all the other simpler questions. Who will spend a few hours reading this question and likely much much more trying to understand whether there is a solution when they could answer dozens of simpler questions instead and get much much more reputation?

Comment: "constructing a nested table for the user interface" Erm, that's a strange part for an MRE for debugging *program logic/algorithm*. Perhaps you should reconsider whether your MRE really is as minimal as possible.

Comment: I don't understand how a "debugging-type question" could be "algorithm-design-related", or vice-versa. If you're trying to figure out what's wrong with something, you are long past the design stage.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel My function (which implements an algorithm) has a problem case (debugging), and this has me wondering whether the entire thing might be better off restructured in a way that's less "fussy" (algorithm design).

Comment: Then you have two possible questions: what's wrong with the code, and how to design the better algorithm. They are not related, and you should pick one. Note that getting an answer to the "what's wrong with the code" question will require you to attempt your own debugging first, and this process should end up narrowing the problem down to something that is different from (smaller than) the task for which you want the new algorithm. (I.e.: what @MisterMiyagi said.)

Comment: I assume it is the Minecraft fluid mechanic question. That's a niche-within-niche question, I wouldn't expect answers to be honest. You are doing some serious greenfield stuff there. I would really find a site or discord channel where Minecraft (Bedrock) mod developers congregate.

Comment: @Gimby I realize few SO contributors specialize in Minecraft addons, *especially* in the subtopic of server-side scripting. In fact, I believe there are only ~3 others besides myself active in the related tags over on Arquade.SE! That's why I came here, instead of asking over there, and did not include the "minecraft" tag even though it exists on SO. I made sure to create a *runnable, interactive* MCVE which demonstrates the entire algorithm in a self-contained way, without requiring knowledge of any Minecraft-specific APIs. I had hoped that would be sufficient to make the Q broader in scope.

Comment: @Gimby Previously, I've asked addon-development-related questions on the Planet Minecraft forum, with mixed success. There are a lot more who are interested in the topic there, but even there scripting is not the main focus. Also, the forum format makes it less likely to get the kind of answers you'd expect on SO.

Comment: @Gimby Still, I appreciate the suggestions! I believe part of the problem is that the beta version of the API (which is the only one I use, since the stable version has so many fewer features) is very new and changes often. *However*, I have made sure to remove all API-specific stuff from the code, as I'm confident the problem is only with my algorithm and not the library. Having significantly edited the question to make it clearer and more compact, do you still believe it's off-topic here?

Comment: There seem to be some pretty arbitrary settings in your situation right now. Prominently, the effect distance of 4 steps - does the issue also occur for a distance of 1, 2, 3 or even 5? Pick the lowest distance at which the issue occurs and state this explicitly. Also, if you know where it recurses infinitely and that one of its guards must fail it should be possible to use debugger or even logging to write out the state when this happens - this should allow you to hardcode the state and get rid of almost all functions but `spreadAboutCenter` and its immediate dependencies.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi 4 is the viscosity of the custom fluid: how many blocks it can spread outward from the source block (inclusive). This is not related to the recursion depth limit of 4, which is just what I've empirically observed is the max depth that should be required for any "non-stuck" configuration. I have now replaced the snippet with a much smaller grid with all the initial block states hardcoded, as you suggested. It turns out, there is one specific "cycle" of recursive calls getting generated back and forth between two particular blocks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Pseudocode is typically useless for debugging questions

Often, the answer to a debugging question is related to some specific detail of the code, and if you don't know the answer already, you have very little chance of correctly describing the code in a way that preserves the bug.  This is especially true if the cause is an implementation error in the logic (as is often the case—everyone makes mistakes).

#### Prefer a minimized runnable example

A *runnable* example ensures that your code really does show the issue. Either recreate it from scratch as a toy example, or take out anything that's not very specifically related to the algorithm you're asking about; only leave things that are either integral to the algorithm itself or essential for context (and can't be described in prose).

Toy examples are fine here: you don't need a full app or UI, just enough to demonstrate the algorithm and the problem.  The character limit on Stack Overflow questions is quite generous; you *really* shouldn't be struggling to stay under it.  I am generally of the opinion that curators here often overemphasize the "minimal" part of "minimal reproducible example"—failed attempts at minimizing the amount of code often leave out important information—but if you're anywhere near the character limit, it's too long.

#### Emphasize the relevant section

Ideally, the most relevant code is easy to find: you shouldn't need to scroll past a bunch of helper code digging for it.  If much of the code is supporting context/helpers for the example, move them to the end, and use prominent comments in the code to indicate which parts can be mostly ignored for the core of the question.

#### Consider if the question can be more focused

If even the smallest possible code sample that shows the issue is huge, you may be asking too much.  Perhaps your question is about one specific part of a larger algorithm, and you can focus it to that specific part.

#### Are there more specific tags you could use?

If the question is complex due to requiring specialized expertise to answer, consider if there are more specific tags to reach relevant experts.  For example, the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) tag will reach a lot of people, but it's a giant firehose of questions, and many of them may not know the specific sub-area you're working with.

Comment: Thank you, @RyanM, for your advice! As matter of fact, the first thing I did before posting the question was to excerpt only the portion of the code pertaining to the specific algorithm, and to take out all API references in order to reduce the problem to plain JS/HTML. The part I was unsure of was how much "context" to leave in, and there I went closer to "as much as possible" than "as little as possible." As the problem function relies on modifying global state, and is asynchronous, I included both it and a related one which is not directly part of the Q, but can also modify the global state

Comment: Function 1 sets up the global state, which is then modified by buggy Function 2, and both 1 and 2 can be running simultaneously (they produce delayed asynchronous calls). After reading your answer, I'm considering eliminating Function 1 entirely (as it's not the source of the problem).

Comment: Where I'm not sure how to proceed is in keeping the example runnable without F.1. I could manually set the user-interactive demo part to the problematic configuration I've identified, which would add more focus at the risk of missing potential edge cases caused by overlapping F1/F2 calls. But, this would still require leaving in the nested table, which another commenter has remarked upon as probably detrimental to its being "minimal." I'm not sure how to keep the demo *runnable* without the table.

Comment: @QuackE.Duck I assume you're referring to [Infinite recursion in fluid physics algorithm - why and how to fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/78173961/208273).  I think the other commenter was commenting on a hypothetical example.  Based on looking at this example, I added an additional "Emphasize the relevant section" part to my answer.  In your question, all the helper code is _first_; if it were at the end with the core algorithm presented more prominently, it would be a lot easier to scan through.

Comment: That is also one where it _is_ kind of a niche question: fluid physics is tricky, and you may have trouble finding people with the expertise to understand that without taking a lot of time.

Comment: Yes, that's the one... I didn't use the "specific-question" tag here because the premise (to use pseudocode or not) should also apply in general. I'll edit the main SO question tonight or tomorrow to move the helper stuff to the bottom: that seems to be the only simple improvement that doesn't risk cutting anything important.